# CK Editor Kama skin download has missing file editor_gecko.css causes issue in loading ckeditor in firefox

Tags: firefox, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have downloaded latest version of ckedit Kama skin from  [here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/kama)

It is unable to load in firefox because editor_gecko.css file is missing.

Has Anyone used this skin? Please share the solution you tried

Comment: Instead of downloading the Kama skin and installing it manually, use [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) to create a custom CKEditor build with the Kama skin included. This will help automatically resolve any dependencies and configuration issues for your build.

Comment: I downloaded as you suggested but still editor_gecko.css file is missing.

Comment: This file is not available for the Kama skin as it is not needed. [Kama skin demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo#skin) works OK for me in Firefox 44.0.2 on Win8.1. **Clear your browser cache**, check the demo, and if this still does not work for you, we need more details. Your browser and OS version? What exactly does it mean that *"it is unable to load in firefox because editor_gecko.css file is missing."*? Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes, "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -  url of editor_gecko.css. My OS is windows 7 and Firefox version - 44.0.2

Comment: Please make sure you really cleared your browser cache ([see this guide here](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache)) and not just refresh the page. If it's still giving you problems, please report a bug on [CKEditor tracker](https://dev.ckeditor.com/). Make sure you include details about your environment, CKEditor version and configuration (`config.js`, `build-config.js` etc.).